# Check Whether person logged in is user or admin in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013

How to check whether the person loggen in user or admin by checking permissions in sharepoint.

Comment: You should mention how are you going to differentiate between user and admin. You want a server side solution or a client side solution? Which version of SharePoint you using? Currently your question is quite vague.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SpServices to determine the permission levels for a user. You can use the below code in document.ready function.

```
$().SPServices({
 operation: "GetRoleCollectionFromUser",
 userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
 async: false,
 completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
$(xData.responseXML).find("Role").each(function() {
      alert($(this).attr('Name'))
   });
```